# Android: How do I configure RelativeLayout to fill the entire height

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a scroll view that contains a relative layout. The scroll view has a gradient background and is set to fill parent. The relative layout also have a BG and i'd like it to fill the screen as well but `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` is not applicable for relative layout.

How can I configure the `RelativeLayout` to span the entire screen height on any screen resolution?

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    style="@style/mainLayoutStyle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/home_activity_bg"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" >


    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**UPDATE:**

I removed everything and left the just the ScrollView and the RelativeLayout, for some reason, on Galaxy S4 the image is cut before the end (you can see according to the blue lines that the Layout itself ends just before the end):

[image]

Comment: Why do you say: "`android:layout_height="fill_parent"` is not applicable for relative layout"?

Comment: I just tried it and fill_parent works just fine for me? Maybe try match parent?

Comment: @RotaryHeart - when i try to set it to fill_parent, eclipse warns me that i should use wrap_content, and when i test it on Galaxy S4 it has no effect.

Comment: You shouldn't, but I have used `"fill_parent"` and `"match_parent"` and even that eclipse say that you shouldn't use them, it works. I did create this layout and it worked for me too. With what @ksudu94 said.

Comment: @RotaryHeart - I tried it on Galaxy S4 and it had not effect, the layout does not fill the height.

Comment: `fill_parent` & `match_parent` will work fine, do you have enough content to fill the screen?

Comment: @RotaryHeart - the idea is that it will fill the screen even if there isn't enough content so the BG will span the entire height and won't cut off in the middle

Comment: Then that should be done if you set it to `"fill_parent"` try removing some all the views and you will see that it should fill the screen. Maybe you have a view that is preventing it to do it.

Comment: What is in "mainLayoutStyle"

Comment: @withoutclass - The only thing it contains is `<item name="android:background">@drawable/gradient_bg</item>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the following code:

```
private void setHeightToFullScreen() {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int height = display.getHeight();
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myRelativeLayout);
        LayoutParams layoutParams = relativeLayout.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = height;
    }
```

please note that `getHeight` is deprecated and you should use `getSize`, but that is only supported in API level 13.

Answer (score 1):

You have that cut because of this "`android:paddingBottom="10dp"` remove that line from your `RelativeLayout` and it will fill the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffff00" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ff0000" >


    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This is my code and this is my display:

[image]

Comment: Tried it already, had no effect, and AFAIK, padding has no effect on the layout height/width span as it is internal, unlike margin which is external

Comment: @fatman In your `style/mainLayoutStyle` you are not changing the height and or padding?

Comment: The only thing it contains is `<item name="android:background">@drawable/gradient_bg</item>`

Comment: @fatman No I'm using that exact code that you see in the post, I just copy and paste it

Comment: Well, what you proved is that the scrollview can fill the parent, but there is no relative layout BG

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40593/discussion-between-rotary-heart-and-fatman)

Answer (score 0):

At the RelativeLayout, remove the `android:paddingBottom="10dp"` and make it `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    style="@style/mainLayoutStyle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/home_activity_bg" >

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```